# SELECT WHERE id ='123' || other_col = other_call

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a select query to retrieve rows where id='123' or where col_x is the same as col_x where id ='123' but the syntax escapes me.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='325' || cart_id IN (SELECT cart_id FROM table WHERE ID='325')
```

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='325' OR other_id = other_id`

Comment: Is `id` the PK of `table`? Does `cart_id` allow `NULL`?

Comment: Got it, and Yes to BOTH, here it is in context
 
`$where.="cart_id = (SELECT cart_id FROM wp_amt_orders WHERE ID = $params)";`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `id` is the PK so can only match at most one row and that `col_x` is not nullable.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  col_x = (SELECT col_x 
                FROM   table 
                WHERE  id = '325')
```

If `id` is a numeric datatype you don't need the single quotes.